# Why do I get compilation error with the fault message "invalid target release 1.17" with Maven?

Tags: java, maven

Below I describe more about the issue I have. I know there are other threads in Stackoverflow but my issue is not resolvded yet,  hence I have tested most of the suggestions.

**Description**
I making a program using Spring REST Interface (see code below) and I have problem to compile code with Maven (see problem section). I have no problem to compile the code using my IDE Eclipse.

**Problem**
When I compile my code with Maven in command line in Windows: mvn clean compile
I get the fault message:
error: invalid target release: 1.17.
Maven and the Java are having the latest versions and the env. varible JAVA_HOME is set to correct Java installationpath:
C:>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.1

C:>java -version
java version "17.0.1" 2021-10-19 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.1+12-LTS-39)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.1+12-LTS-39, mixed mode, sharing)

C:>mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.8.4 (9b656c72d54e5bacbed989b64718c159fe39b537)
Maven home: C:\tobbe\apache-maven-3.8.4
Java version: 17.0.1, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.1
Default locale: sv_SE, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

I have tried several different versions of both Java and Maven but with same error. I have reduced source/target in POM and I get the same fault when versions are between 11-17 and lower version  gives souce code compilation fault because probably version is to low.

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>tobbe</groupId>
    <artifactId>stocks-rest</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>tobbe</groupId>
        <artifactId>Stocks_Backend</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And my code:

```
/**
 * Version 1.0.2
 */
package Rest;

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.instrument.IllegalClassFormatException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.server.ServletWebServerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import Enums.Market;
import Enums.REA_Stock_State;
import Enums.Stock_State;
import REA.REAMain;
import REA.REAStock;
import Stocks.Logger;
import mExceptions.ElementSizeException;

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class StocksRestApi 
{
    private Logger iLogger = null; 
    
    public StocksRestApi()
    {
        iLogger = new Logger();   
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        SpringApplication.run(StocksRestApi.class, args);
    }
    
    @GetMapping(value="/logdata")
    public String logdata() 
    {
        List<String> dataLogList = iLogger.getLogData();
        String dataLog = "";
        
        if(dataLogList.size() == 0)
        {
            dataLog = "Run http://localhost:8080/rea first"; 
        }
        
        for(String row: dataLogList)
        {
            dataLog += row;  
        }
        
        return dataLog; 
    }
}
```

**Question**
Why do I get invalid target release 1.17 when I compile my code with Maven?

Comment: I would suggest to use `<maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>`... and the problem is use `17` instead of `1.17` this has been changed since JDK9...as described in the answer...

Comment: Correcting the versions gives compilation fault of sorce code which I don't get in Eclipse: 
 /C:/tobbe/eclipse/student-services/src/main/java/Rest/StocksRestApi.java:[28,19] package mExceptions does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/tobbe/eclipse/student-services/src/main/java/Rest/StocksRestApi.java:[83,91] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ElementSizeException
[ERROR]   location: class Rest.StocksRestApi

Which are: 
import mExceptions.ElementSizeException;
and
public String rea() throws ElementSizeException

Comment: Which JDK version is configured in Eclipse? Second if this a spring boot application which looks like this the usage maven-assembly-plugin is wrong. Use spring-boot-maven-plugin for this..

Comment: 1.17 is choosen in Eclipse aswell, I don't have other Java JDKs installed now. I had plugin assembler because I wanted to create an executable jar from Maven. I still can't compile project because a failing import. Missing class is in jar in m2 so I don't understand why compilation fails (works in Eclipse).  It is a own exception that fails when importing it:.

Comment: package Exceptions;

public class ElementSizeException extends Exception
{
 public ElementSizeException(String aErrorMsg)
 {
  super(aErrorMsg); 
 }
}

Comment: As mentioned in the answers change the configuration in your pom file...

Comment: Sorry but how should the pom look like? I'm quite new in Maven..

Answer (score 7):

Because there is no Java 1.17 release. They stopped putting `1` in front of version numbers. It was confusing. So they stopped with [Java 9](https://www.infoq.com/news/2015/12/java-version-strings-evolve/) (see also [JEP223](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/223)). Use

```
<maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
```